# git branch pretty format '%C(always/auto)'

Tags: git, git-branch, pretty-print

I'm trying to create an alias for a particular view of my git branches, with the usual verbose data plus some extra. (Datetime; I'm also sorting by date.) This is possible with a custom format string, but it loses the default coloring from `git branch -v`; the active branch doesn't get highlighted in green and other coloring like upstreams doesn't show up either. It looks to me from [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) like this should be fixed by adding `%C(always)`  as a prefix to the format string, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
git branch --format=:%C(always) %(committerdate:short) %(refname:short) %(contents:lines=1)"
```

just displays

```
%C(always) 2022-08-23 foo/bar testing Token
%C(always) 2022-08-26 seethefnords fix validation
```

with no color. What is wrong here?

(Also, just incidentally, is it possible to get the smart alignment back in a custom format string?)

Answer (score 1):

> just displays
>
> ```
> %C(always) 2022-08-23 foo/bar testing Token
> ```

Then the first thing to check is your Git version.

`%C(always)` was introduced with [Git commit 4261775](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42617752d4b22d616e276528ba4d155e6fff1835), Git 2.22 (Q2 2019).
Which means you might be using an older Git version.

```
git version
```

Comment: (For future reference, I checked and this covers `%C(auto)` as well, those weren't deployed separately.)

Comment: @jkmartin OK. What version of Git are you using? (and on which OS and shell?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *short* answer: `git branch` does not obey the pretty format directives you've linked.  Those are for `git log` only.

Comment: Why not? Where is this documented?

Comment: (1) You'll need to ask the Git authors. (2) The `git branch` documentation refers one to the `git for-each-ref` documentation, which describes its (different) formatting directives.